# How to automize the config export to a custom distribution

Tags: configuration, distributions

We use a custom Drupal distribution on our websites. There are also our custom modules in the distribution. The modules contain configurations.

When I change some configurations in Drupal Administration and export them with `drush cex`, they are updated only at the config/sync folder, but not in the distribution. I have to find the configs, copy them to the custom distribution modules and delete uuid and _core.

Is there some way, how to automize the config export to the distribution?

Comment: Don't you just manually need to copy them into the right place and remove the config UUID? I guess it's hard to automate that as there would need to be a way that this automation-mechanism needs to know beforehand where the original distro config came from (spread across multiple custom modules probably), but I'd like to be proven wrong.

Comment: It is not so easy, when you have to update many configs in multiple custom distribution modules. If no automation exists, then I will write a shell script or a drush command. Till now, I have found nothing, what I could use.

Comment: I also had this problem. I stopped using custom profiles at all, and instead use a workflow based on the minimal profile with `drush site:install --existing-config` to save the work of manually updating the profile.

Comment: It looks like I came to the exactly the same conclusion as you, Antonin. We maintain a perfectly-configured base Drupal installation, and every time it changes I run a "sync config" script that uses bash and Drush to export the config, copy it to the profile, and remove the UUIDs and _core from all files.

Comment: Hi @Geat is the "sync config" script publically available?

Comment: It's not, @AntonínSlejška - but it's not too complicated. I export the config with `drush` (config:export), copy the exported files to the /config/install folder of the profile, remove "core.extension.yml" and "update.settings.yml", then use `sed` to remove the uuid and core entries.